# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'RepositoryResponse[]'. Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest, axios, interface

I am trying to fetch data from the GitHub API, but give me the error that values from the API does not exist in the interface.
API URL : https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react

```
      interface Repository {
      name: string;
      avatar_url: string;
      html_url: string;
      owner : {
        login: string;
      }
    }
    
    interface RepositoryResponse {
      data: Repository
    }


  const [repositoryData,setRepositoryData] = useState<RepositoryResponse[]>([]);


//Component

<p> {repositoryData.name}  </p>
<p>   {repositoryData.owner.login}  </p>
<p> {repositoryData.html_url}  </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

repositoryData is an array of RepositoryResponse which contains one filed data which is a Repository.

```js
repositoryData.map({data} => {return (
<p> {data.name}  </p>
<p>{data.owner.login}</p>
<p> {data.html_url}</p>)
})
```

Comment: the syntaxt gives an error

Comment: What error? I have not tested the code since the code provided was not complete. This answer is you an example of how you could solve it